# digits missing when using twilio.js

Tags: twilio

when using SendDigits to send 9999, the digits received on the other end come back as a single 9.

it seems to happen whenever the numbers are repeated.  sending 9876 works as expected.

This does NOT occur with the ios and android versions, just the javascript library.

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  This sounds like a situation where an email to help@twilio.com is be best idea.  If you can include some call sids of calls that exhibit the incorrect behavior they can dig into those calls and see if we are actually receiving the digits and just not passing them through, or something else.